# How to convert a html table obtained as a parameter on success of a Jquery $.get method

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a Jquery $.get function which calls a controller which in turn returns a View containing a html table.

```
 $.get("/VM/VmProcesses?pr=" + processes, function (process) 
 {
        oTable.fnOpen(nTr, process, 'table');
 }
```

This works fine and displays the table as intended. But i cant get this returned table to convert to a datatable using Jquery datatable() method as shown below.

```
 $.get("/VM/VmProcesses?pr=" + processes, function (process) 
 {
        oTable.fnOpen(nTr, process, 'table');
        $('#mytable').datatable();
 }
```

I get an error **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datatable is not a function**
Any way to get this working ? Also, i tried converting the table in the view itself and that didnt work either.

Comment: did you attach "datatable.js"?

Comment: @diavolic Yes , i have attached it once in the main layout file

Comment: and post here html code for your table too

Comment: I am little confused. In your first code section, your are just displaying `$.get response` which is html table but why are you using [datatable fnOpen](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnOpen)  *`oTable.fnOpen(nTr, process, 'table');`* in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Should it be:

```
 $('#mytable').DataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Gen Answer, Please make sure you have added relevant script files to your page,

//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
For Style
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datatable is not a function

Comment: Can you check this link?
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Comment: And also i have share Plunker link here with  please check this too
https://embed.plnkr.co/cZlaCQ3htUtp4iM7tX1b/

Answer (score 0):

So i could solve this by adding the $("#mytable").datatable() in the view itself and in the Document.ready method. Still unsure why it didn't work in the success response function